# Enabling offline capabilities throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist."

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to migrate my app to Firebase 3. I'm attemping to enable data persistence in my Application class using the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

However, the following exception is thrown and the app crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

All other features are working as expected, has anyone else got this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment this line in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
```

Comment: It's looking like this worked... but why? I still get the line in my logcat: "FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization." which is odd.

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you haven't provided google-services.json for your app, as said in step 4 here [Add Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app) or didn't apply google services plugin

Answer (score 0):

I put `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` to `onCreate` in `MainActivity` and no longer error.

```html
MainActivity.java

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: This works due to a known issue with concurrency, as outlined here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues

Answer (score 0):

recently i changed this line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
```

changed back to 9.0.0 fix it for me.